# Bits impares =1, de un entero a binario

Tags: c

Asumiendo w=32 ,escribir un programa que regrese 1 cuando cualquier bit impar es igual  1 , 0 en caso contrario.

Se me ocurre ingresar un entero x, luego pasarlo a binario (en 32 bits) y éste en un arreglo [32] para leer las entradas impares, no se si sea correcto ya que la pregunta no parece estar bien formulada

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Qué pasa cuando implementas lo que crees que harías?

Comment: Quiero saber si es correcta mi interpretación y de ser así como seria el código. Gracias

Comment: Aquí no te van a dar _el código correcto_. Por eso mi pregunta sobre la implementación de tu aproximación. Aquí podemos ayudarte todos a resolver los problemas que tengas con tu código. Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio. También estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Cuando hay que andar mirando bits, la solución suele usar algún operador _bitwise_, es decir, que haga operaciones bit a bit. Por ejemplo, puedes hacer una operación `&` con un dato de valor binario `101010101010...1010` (32 bits). Como ves tiene 0 en las posiciones pares, por lo que el resultado en esas posiciones será 0 independientemente de lo que hubiera en el dato original. En cambio en las impares tiene 1, por lo que si hay algún 1 en esas posiciones, el resultado tendrá de nuevo un 1 en las mismas. Sólo si el resultado es 0 significará que todos los bits impares del dato eran cero.